# Handlebars If var length is greater than

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, zurb-foundation

I'm currently trying to set up some email templates using Foundation email and Handlebars. Im trying to render some headings based on if a value is passed to the component, however I can't seem to get it to work. What am i doing wrong here?

heading-1.html

```
<h1>{{text}}</h1>
```

paragraph.html

```
<row class="card">
    <columns>
        <wrapper class="inner-padding">
            {{#if (eq heading-1.length > 0)}}
                {{> heading-1 text="Test"}}
            {{else}}
                <h1>failed</h1>
            {{/if}}
            <p>
                {{text}}
            </p>
        </wrapper>
    </columns>
</row>
```

index.html

```
<container>
  <row>
    <columns class="content">
      {{> paragraph
        heading-1="test"
        text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet dolorem molestias nam odit suscipit velit.
        Ab aliquam at autem dignissimos dolorum ipsam magnam molestiae officia, quae quo, veniam veritatis voluptatibus?"
      }}
    </columns>
  </row>
</container>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create Handlebars helper :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('checklength', function (v1, v2, options) {
'use strict';
   if (v1.length>v2) {
     return options.fn(this);
  }
  return options.inverse(this);
});
```

Use :

```
{{#checklength Title 0}}   //Title is property and 0 is length
             <p>Heading</p>
      {{else}}
             <h1>failed</h1>
      {{/checklength}}
```